# get Field value from Firestore with flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection called parent contains an attribute called class, I want to return the value of this attribute for a document That I'm specified in the code,

I managed to print the value but I cannot return the value for using it in a comparison after .

```
getSpecie(idetud) async {
DocumentReference documentReference = parsref.doc(idetud);
int specie = 0;
await documentReference.get().then((snapshot) {
  specie = snapshot["classe"];
  print(
      "======================================================================== field value");
  print(specie); // this works good 
});
return specie; // but this no !!!!
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what happens is that the print works because it is inside the then() but the return does not, when you call the method it follows the flow and specie in the last line still does not have the expected value. If so, you have to wait for that value.

```
getSpecie(idetud) async {
  DocumentReference documentReference = parsref.doc(idetud);
  var snapshot = await documentReference.get();
  return snapshot["classe"];
}
```

Comment: Now when i want to get the idetud ( document id of  collection parents where the email is equal to the current user email ) how i can do it !!???

Comment: I dont't know how your object is, but you can use something like this:
collection.firstWhere((document) => document.email == currentUser.email).id;